# Can I use the Instagram API to post from my Mobile app straight to Instagram

Tags: api, mobile, instagram

We would like to have our users be able to click a button on our app and then open up or post straight to Instagram.  Can this be done with the current API tey have accessible to developers?

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible there is no API to post directly to Instagram.

You can open Instagram app with a image u want to post from your app: https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/